# Reference Request: Error estimation with Runge Kutta method with continuous finite elements

Tags: reference-request, finite-element-method

Let the Heat equation or some other partial differential equation. I seek some reference in which there exists error analysis concerning the fully-discrete scheme with the finite element method (continuous) in spatial variable and a Runge - Kutta method in time variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very in-depth book is:
Numerical Solution of Time-Dependent Advection-Diffusion-Reaction Equations by Willem Hundsdorfer, Jan Verwer.

The heat equation is a special case of advection-diffusion where advection is zero.